# how to add kendo editor tool image which is not in sprite.png

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-editor

[image]
Image shows the last icon which do not have image in sprite.png and i have tried to add font awesome icon image and even it is not working.
I am using kendo-ui 2021 version now.
This is the code I am using and I am unable to add icon image print,clear formation and copy format.

```
****$("#a").kendoEditor({
            imageBrowser: {
                transport: {
                    read: "@Url.Action("Read", "Controllername")",
                    destroy: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("Destroy", "Controllername")",
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Controllername")",
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                    thumbnailUrl: "@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Controllername")",
                    uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("Upload", "Controllername")",
                    imageUrl: "@Url.Action("Image?path={0}", "Controllername")",
                }
            },
            tools: [
                "formatting",
                "bold",
                "italic",
                "underline",
                "strikethrough",
                "justifyLeft",
                "justifyCenter",
                "justifyRight",
                "justifyFull",
                "insertUnorderedList",
                "insertOrderedList",
                "indent",
                "outdent",
                "createLink",
                "unlink",
                "insertImage",
                "subscript",
                "superscript",
                "tableWizard",
                "createTable",
                "addRowAbove",
                "addRowBelow",
                "addColumnLeft",
                "addColumnRight",
                "deleteRow",
                "deleteColumn",
                "foreColor",
                "backColor",
                "print"
            ],
            execute: function (e) {
                var editor = this;
                if (e.name == "createtable") {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var table = $(editor.body).find("table:not(.custom-table)");
                        table.addClass("custom-table");
                        table.attr("style", "border: 1px solid black;");
                        table.find("tr td")
                            .each(function () {
                                var currentStyle = $(this).attr("style");
                                $(this).attr("style", currentStyle + " border: 1px solid black; ");
                            });
                    }, 0);
                }                
            }           
        });****
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using customer tools in kendo, and insert the relevant images as png and give the image url in style tag.

**code inside the kendoEditor:**

```
     $("#quest").kendoEditor({
       tools[{
                name: "print",
                tooltip: "print",
                exec: function (e) {
                }
            }
```

]

**styles:**

```
<style>

.k-editor .k-i-print {
 background: 50% 50% no-repeat 
              url(https://localhost/cisiweb2/image/master/print.png);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: but I was not able to done the same thing to the  other 2 icons copy format and apply format

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).